# how to joint two table in codeigniter with jquery data table

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

this is the code i m using but it,s not working:my joint query is ok i test it on simple controller with out jquery datatable and it work,but in joint i can,t get data from second table to show on edit modal

```
//controller

        public function ajax_edit($ID_Student)
            {
                $data = $this->person->get_by_id($ID_Student);
                echo json_encode($data);
            }

    //mdel
        public function get_by_id($ID_Student)
            {
                $this->db->from($this->table);
                $this->db->where('ID_Student',$ID_Student);
                $this->db->join('section', 'student.sec_id = section.sec_id',
           'left outer'); 
                $query = $this->db->get();

                return $query->row();
            }
```

Comment: anyone give me solotion please

Comment: check if the value present in get_by_id function for  `$ID_Student`

Comment: Do you have a property $table inside the model? Because that's not shown in your code.

Comment: yes i have that

Comment: if i m not use jquerydata table then it,s working ,but in jquery data table it, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check while passing to controller through jquery, $ID_Student is not empty.

updated: Use simple inner join instead of left outer join to get data matching from both the tables.

Comment: no it,s not empty if i m not joint table then it,s getting data from student table, but when i joint the it,s get data form one table not from other

Comment: you are using `left outer` in you join query. Left join gives data matching from left table. Remove that and use inner join. Inner join gives data matching both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

i created a codeigniter model for datatables.

maybe that can help you, check at https://github.com/moellmaster/codeigniter-datatables